# Как вывести элемент из списка во вложенном словаре, находящемся в списке?

Tags: python

```
a = { "x" : [{"y": ["z", ] } ] }
```

Как, допустим, вывести отсюда элемент "z" ?

Comment: пройтись по всему объекту

Answer (score 1):

Правильное форматирование структуры данных - ключ к пониманию доступа к её элементам:

```
a = {"x" : 
      [
        {"y": 
          [
            "z", 
          ] 
        } 
      ] 
    }
```

Что мы видим? Словарь->список->словарь->список. Соответственно к словарям обращаемся по ключу, а из списков берём первый элемент (с индексом 0):

```
print(a["x"][0]["y"][0])
# z
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробный пример решения:

```
a = { "x" : [{"y": ["z", ] } ] }
for key, value in a.items(): # берем ключ и значение словаря 'a'
    for value_list in value: # берем из значения словаря 'a' (из списка) сложенный словарь
        for key_2, value_2 in value_list.items(): # из вложенного второго словаря берем ключ и значение
            for i in value_2: # из значения второго словаря (из списка) берем значние
                print(i) # выводим значение
```

И, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с правилами stackoverflow.

С ними вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)